# Time difference between different stages in data set

Tags: sql, oracle

I was wondering if you could help me out.  Im not sure if this is possible but given the table of data below I was wondering if it is possible to write a query that could easily show the time taken for each car between the carViewed and carBought stage.  Ideally I would like to see the carID along with the time. For example the results should be something like this:

| CarID | TimeDifference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:17:83 |
| 2 | 00:04:21 |
| 3 | 01:57:83 |

Data

| CarID | Stage | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | carArrived | 2022-01-20 13:00:00 |
| 1 | carViewed | 2022-01-20 14:00:00 |
| 1 | carBought | 2022-01-20 14:17:83 |
| 1 | carLeft | 2022-01-20 15:17:83 |
| 2 | carArrived | 2022-01-21 15:00:00 |
| 2 | carViewed | 2022-01-21 16:00:00 |
| 2 | carBought | 2022-01-21 16:04:21 |
| 2 | carLeft | 2022-01-21 16:27:83 |
| 3 | carArrived | 2022-01-22 13:00:00 |
| 3 | carViewed | 2022-01-22 14:00:00 |
| 3 | carBought | 2022-01-22 15:57:83 |
| 3 | carLeft | 2022-01-22 16:17:83 |

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY. Use case expressions to get carViewed and carBought. Or do a self join.

Comment: There are only 60 seconds in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT carid,
       MAX(CASE stage WHEN 'carBought' THEN timestamp END)
         - MIN(CASE stage WHEN 'carViewed' THEN timestamp END) AS timeDifference
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY carid
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (CarID, Stage, Timestamp) AS
SELECT 1, 'carArrived', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-20 13:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'carViewed',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-20 14:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'carBought',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-20 14:17:53' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'carLeft',    TIMESTAMP '2022-01-20 15:17:53' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'carArrived', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-21 15:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'carViewed',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-21 16:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'carBought',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-21 16:04:21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'carLeft',    TIMESTAMP '2022-01-21 16:27:53' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'carArrived', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-22 13:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'carViewed',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-22 14:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'carBought',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-22 15:57:53' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'carLeft',    TIMESTAMP '2022-01-22 16:17:53' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CARID | TIMEDIFFERENCE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | +000000000 00:17:53.000000000 |
> | 2 | +000000000 00:04:21.000000000 |
> | 3 | +000000000 01:57:53.000000000 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9643064521ed06c716736cdb88be7775)*